Azure DevOps YAML builds not respecting triggers on Default branches when pipeline file is modified
Have a project where completed PRs to the Default branch (main) are not triggering builds after the PR is completed.
Below is the pipeline that I've setup with a repo that contains a few text files.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - main

stages:
- stage: TestTrigger
  displayName: 'Test'
  jobs:
    - job: Test
      displayName: 'Test Triggers'
      workspace:
        clean: all
      pool: MyHostedPool
      steps:
        - checkout: self
        - powershell: |
            Write-Output "Hello World2"
          displayName: 'Run Script'

When I commit changes to dev/main the triggers work as expected however if I change the azure-pipelines.yml file either directly on the 'Default' branch or as part of a PR to the Default branch the pipeline does not trigger.

I've changed the default branch from main to dev and then the main branch and main works as expected but dev stops triggering when there are changes to the azure-pipelines.yml file.
Has anybody else seen this? If so, do you have a work-around or a bug report from Microsoft on this one?
I know this can be solved by using the 'Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here' option on the pipeline definition.
Screenshot to show the pipeline triggers on a TestFile.txt but updates to the azure-pipelines.yml (through pipeline editor and PR) did not trigger the build


Can you share some screenshots to help understand your operations to change the azure-pipelines.yml file either directly on the 'Default' branch and as part of a PR to the Default branch the pipeline?

When you say "As part of a PR", do you mean when completing the PR, or when the PR is still open? Because if it's the latter, that's expected behavior.

By I've changed the default branch from main to dev and then the main branch and main works as expected but dev stops triggering when there are changes to the azure-pipelines.yml file. What default branch do you mean? The problematic pipeline default branch or the default branch of the repo? Do you mean your pipeline can only be triggered by the commit pushed to the azure-pipelines.yml file in the non default branch? Can you please share more details like screenshots to help understand the issue-reproducing steps? Don't forget to scrub or remove any private/sensitive information. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT - Minor changes such as changing the display name on a task. Nothing that modifies the triggers. The changing of the default branch refers to the configuration in Azure DevOps that allows you to set the 'Default' and 'Compare' branches (Project --> Repos --> Branches). In this example there are only 2 branches dev and main and yes they have the azure-pipelines.yml file.

@DanielMann - Complete the PR meaning the PR is approved and closed and the code is then merged to the target branch (and that target branch is main) and the build fails to trigger.

Steps to reproduce


Create a new repository with a main branch when it is initialized.


Commit/Push the azure-pipelines.yml (like above) and a text file to the main branch (should automatically create the pipeline for you)


Make a dev branch from the main branch.


On dev, Commit/push to any file and the build will trigger as expected.


On main, Commit/push to the text file only the build will trigger as expected.


On main, Commit/push to the azure-pipelines.yml the build will not trigger. (Simple changes like modifying a displayName)



When was the pipeline created? Was it created with an existing yaml definition after your Commit/Push the azure-pipelines.yml into main branch @step2? Or was it created with an existing yaml definition in dev branch after you created the dev branch @step3?

The behavior is the same if it is a new azure-pipelines.yml file or if it's a modification to the existing file.

Besides, how many pipelines were created referencing the same azure-pipelines.yml definition file? Can you share a screenshot of the History tab of the file azure-pipelines.yml on main branch in your repo web UI, where we should be able to see the status of pipeline(s)' run(s) of each commit.

Would you have a test to use the pipeline editor, switch to main branch and modify  azure-pipelines.yml definition with some dummy contents, then save such 2 continuous edits on the main branch? Will the pipeline be triggered by the 2nd push?

The pipeline does not trigger in this case

There is only 1 pipeline for this azure-pipelines.yml file. Included a screenshot from the history on the main branch to show commits to files that are not the azure-pipelines.yml file trigger the build however updates to YAML are not triggering the build.
The edits in that history are only minor changes to task names.

Is the issue reproducible with the sample definition file in a new repo? It's really confusing why the repo default branch may affect the CI trigger of the pipeline generated from the self repo.

Agreed, Created the sample and it worked as expected. I also went back to the original repo/pipeline that was having the issue and it is no longer exhibiting the behavior. I'll keep an eye on it and see if it happens again. Another one of those unsolved mysteries of Microsoft.

Sure and please feel welcome to share more findings if you observe any more behaviors. Thx.
